# Why I can't drag folder file to github repo in Google Chrome new version

Tags: google-chrome, github, repository, directory

I want to upload my folder file to github repo, but when i drag the folder file into github repo that disable/can't drag.

[My screenshot can't dragged the folder file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMQTD.png)